# Generic ArrayList with multiple parameters (classes) with an own add method

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have 5 classes:

- Ant {abstract},
- Worker extends Ant,
- Soldier extends Ant,
- Queen extends Ant,
- Anthill

  ```
  public class Anthill<T extends Ant> {

  ArrayList <Ant> antHill = new ArrayList<>();

  public void adde(T ant)
  {
  if(ant != null)
  {
      if (ant.isQueen() == true && amountOfQueens <= 1)
      {
              antHill.add(ant);
              amountOfQueens++;

      } 
          else if (ant.isQueen() == false) 
              {
              antHill.add(ant);
              amountOfAnts++;
              }
       else   
                  { 
                  System.out.println("Only one queen is permitted.");
                  }
  }

  }
  ```

---

example:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args){

    ArrayList <Ant> antList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 1; i<6; i++){
        antList.adde(new Worker(6, "AW", 0, i));

    }
```

The problem is that I want to add any kind of ants (Soldier, Queen, Worker) into the ArrayList using my own `public void adde(T ant)` method.

I get the error that the method adde(Worker) is undefined for the type ArrayList.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? It only works when using the method `add()` but I have to use my own one.

Comment: You'd need to call `adde` on an `Anthill` rather than an `ArrayList`. This doesn't have anything to do with generics.

Comment: I also don't see a reason why ```Anthill``` would be a generic class, unless you plan to have ```Anthill```s that have only ```Worker```s, or only ```Queen```s.

Comment: You actually do not need the generic notation on your class at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that I want to add any kind of ants (Soldier, Queen, Worker) into the ArrayList using my own public void adde(T ant) method.

i'm assuming you want to add elements in the `ArrayList antHill` defined into the Anthill class.  The reason of my assumptions is that it seems that you want to keep count of "population" of the Anthill and if there's a queen into it.

> I get the error that the method adde(Worker) is undefined for the type ArrayList.

to invoke the method `adde` from the class Anthill, you first have to instantiate the class, to call the method `adde` on the object just created. Since an ArrayList Instance is NOT an Anthill instance, you cannot invoke an Anthill's method on an ArrayList instance .

> Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? It only works when using the method add() but I have to use my own one.

for the class Anthill itself you cannot use generics, because it would lead to Instances of the class Anthills of just Worker OR Soldier OR Queen elements, and will not of course contain at once all types derived from the class Ant but just one. Moreover the `adde` method parameter  `ant` in `public void adde(T ant)` must be of super-type `Ant` so you can pass any subtype to the method.

Next in the main method create an instance of Anthill and call on it (not in the `ArrayList antList`) the method `adde`.

it looks like this:

```
public class Anthill {

    ArrayList <Ant> antHill = new ArrayList<>();

    public void adde(Ant ant)
    {
        if(ant != null)
        {
        // Assuming ant.isQueen() returns a boolean.
        // amountOfQueens must be 0 to permit the insertion of max 1 Queen instance in the list
        if (ant.isQueen() && amountOfQueens == 0)
        {
            antHill.add(ant);
            amountOfQueens++;
        } 
        else if (ant.isQueen() == false) 
        {
            antHill.add(ant);
            amountOfAnts++;
        }
        else   
        { 
            System.out.println("Only one queen is permitted.");
        }
    }
}
```

here the Main.java :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        Anthill antHill = new Anthill();

        for(int i = 1; i<6; i++)
        {
            antHill.adde(new Worker(6, "AW", 0, i));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to read and exercise using [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) for a reference on the language structures and use cases, naming conventions and to learn an effective use of the language. Regards